# AVAudioPlayer iOS Error

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I get an error trying to play a clip using AVAudioPlayer. The error gives me:

> 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)'

I have no idea. The frameworks are all there etc...

Is it something to do with the URL?

Here's my code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"grunt" ofType:@"aiff"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:soundFilePath];
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
    if(!error){
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [audioPlayer play];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error loading clip: %@", [error localizedDescription]); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried NSURL +[fileURLWithPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath%3a)?